# Portable gcc for linux

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, portability

is there a suite of portable build tools for linux including at least make and gcc?

I would like to use for a portable build environment.

Best regards

Comment: Would `configure`ing with `--prefix=...` not help?

Comment: this would mean that i need to compile gcc myself :)

Comment: I assume that you meant portable installations of `gcc` and dependencies.  If that is correct, then yes.  You'll need to build `gcc`.

Comment: so, in a nutshell i will just need to set the prefix to some custom dir in my home, and this dir would be the portable gcc version then?

Comment: Hmm.. not that simple perhaps.  You'll need to go the same for dependencies and build `gcc` using the thus compiled dependencies.

Comment: *cry cry*, i wonder why there is no portable release

Comment: Maybe you can try finding if *binaries* are available for your platform.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34223/discussion-between-stasik-and-devnull)

Answer (score -2):

Probably you can take a look on that:

[Portable C Compiler](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/), with some [How-to](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/how-it-works/)

Comment: Yes, it's not gcc in fact. You really need it to be gcc? And with pcc you won't get any 'make' tool, sadly. I suppose that the only way to get fully portable GCC (not something similar) is to compile it yourself, as devnull pointed above